# How do I display an image in SSH terminal?

Tags: command-line, ssh, png

I want to access/view to a image on a remote Ubuntu server, to which I only have SSH access.

Specifically, it is a black-and-white qr code `.png` image, and I want to scan it with my qr code scanner device.

I have tried [caca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca), but the displayed image is not recognized by my scanner.

Comment: Why not just copy the file to local system and display it from there? `scp [user]@[host]:/[path]/[image].png . && display [image].png`

Comment: Thanks, copy file from scp is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running X windows on your local system, the `-X` or `-Y` options to `ssh` will let the remote system display images on your local X display. See `man ssh` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh.1.html

Comment: Sadly I have no root permission to modify remote server `ForwardX11` option.